# Solving one dimensional heat equation with boundary conditons PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the non-homogeneous boundary value problem for the one dimensional heat equation on a bar with unit length and $c=1$, for the following data:
$u(0,t)=100$; $u(1,t)=50$: $u(x,0)=x$

---

I am assuming I am supposed to use the equation form $u_t=cu_{xx}$ and solve it using separation of variables but how do I use the initial conditions within the separation of variables process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to transform your heat equation with a change of variables using the equilibrium solution to something that is more manageable and that you know how to solve.

First of all you want to find some sort of equilibrium solution $u_E$. An equilibrium solution tells you what the rod looks like after a really long time, when it is stable and isn't changing any more. To get the equilibrium solution, set $u_t=0$ because you want it to not be changing with time, so you get.
$u_{xx}=0 \iff u_E(x)=Ax+B$, now apply boundary conditions to it to get A and B.

Then your change of variables will be $$v(x,t) = u(x,t)-u_E(x)$$ and now if you plug everything in, you should see that it transforms to a problem you know how to solve ($v(0,t)=v(1,t)=0$)

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out from there actually, I just missed the implications that the boundary conditions force and then I realized that I needed to solve the two systems seperately with them being joint by $\lambda$.